# ¿Por que al usar document.write() se borra todo lo anterior de la pagina?

Tags: javascript, java

En mi código es una calculadora al ingresar los datos y darle a botón para que ejecute la función donde al final viene un document.write() da el resultado correcto pero se sobre pone ante el formato del body anterior, solo que no se si existe otro comando que me pueda serivir.

PD: soy nuevo en programación y autodidacta cualquier tipo de comenatario o sugerencia se los agradeceria.

Comment: por que estas volviendo a escribir el contenido \\_(°-°)_/

Comment: Pero no quiero sobre ponerlo solo quiero agregar ese párrafo al ya existente

Comment: crea un contenedor y agrega los datos que quieras

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Conviene siempre leer la documentación de lo que estamos usando.

Sobre [`document.write()` hay una nota bastante clara en MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Document/write):

> **Nota**: dado que `document.write` escribe directo al hilo (stream) de un documento, la llamada a `document.write` en un documento ya
> cargado automáticamente ejecuta `document.open`, lo cual [limpiará
> todo el contenido del documento en cuestión](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.open#Notes).

Comment: Y si no quiero limpiar el contenido, solo quiero agregarla como  un <p></p> mas?

Comment: @RodrigoNAVARRO podrías usar [`innerHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML) u otro método. Javascript tiene varias formas de agregar contenido al DOM.